# Naruto time skip before 4th great ninja war

Tags: naruto

I was wondering what happend between march and october(before the 4th great ninja war).There is a time skip of about 6 months and i don't know what's happening in this time.

Comment: Could you add either chapter or episode numbers as a references? It's been a while since I've watched the anime, but I don't recall there being a 6 month time skip prior to the 4th shinobi war

Comment: @Wondercricket i found this article https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/User:Seelentau/Naruto_Timeline?useskin=oasis